# radio button to show div on loading a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

The problem I have with the below is that I'm working with a form that gets passed thru several different stages and the click function triggers the 'show'.

Is there a way to have the show triggered by a similar thing to onload?

so to explain the bigger picture here. I've got a form with a radio button to 'add an image'. stage 1 of the form is for the author. stage 2 of the form is for the content editor. so the form is completed and passed to the content editor. if the radio button is checked at stage 1 the div is shown. when this form is passed to stage 2 I need the div to still be shown. hope this explains my problem further.

stage 2 is a completely different page.

Sorry this is my first time on here!

#### Markup

```
<input type = radio id = "image1" name = "image1" > image 1 </input>
<input type = radio id = "image2" name = "image2" > image 2 </input>
<div id= "div-id1" style="display:none"> image 1</div>
<div id= "div-id2" style="display:none"> image 2</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$("#image1").click(function(){

    if ($("#image1").is(":checked")) {
      //show the hidden div
       $("#div-id1").show("slide");
    } 
    else {
      $("#div-id1").hide("slide");
    }
});

$("#image2").click(function(){
    if ($("#image2").is(":checked")) {
      //show the hidden div
      $("#div-id2").show("slide");
    } 
    else {
      $("#div-id2").hide("slide");
    }
});
```

Comment: [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show()`'s](http://api.jquery.com/show/) first argument is duration.

Comment: @Christopher hey mate add it as answer.

Comment: @Christopher jquery UI has different param http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/hide

Comment: @phobos, I don't think jQuery UI is being used here though.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Alright @user2194969, how's that? (check new answer)

Answer (score 0):

try this.It is working for me [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LWLwh/1/)

```
$("#image1").click(function(){
    if ($("#image1").is(":checked")) {
      //show the hidden div
       $("#div-id1").show();

    }
});

$("#image2").click(function(){
    if ($("#image2").is(":checked")) {
      //show the hidden div
      $("#div-id2").show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Are you going to explain what you did?

Comment: @ Christopher here i am showing corresponding div and hiding another div.Is there any wrong in this.

Comment: I need to show each div at all times when the radio button is selected.

Comment: @user2194969 i modified my code see it once.Sorry i misunderstand the question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#image1").click(function(){

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

     $("#div-id1").show("slide up");

}
});
$("#image2").click(function(){

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

     $("#div-id2").fadeIn("slow");
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilmani/2CJdd/

Answer (score 0):

[`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) in jQuery take a `duration` as the first argument.

There is a `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` function but I don't think that's what you want.

[Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/AgkR6/20/)

#### New Markup

```
<input type="checkbox" id="image1" class="imageBox" name="image1" checked>image 1</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="image2" class="imageBox" name="image2">image 2</input>
<div id="image1Container" class="imageContainer" style="display:none">image 1</div>
<div id="image2Container" class="imageContainer" style="display:none">image 2</div>
```

#### Corresponding code

```
(function () {
    var showImgBlock = function (img, container) {
        (img.is(":checked")) ? container.show(500) : container.hide(300);
    };

    $(".imageBox").each(function () {
        item = this.id;
        showImgBlock($("#" + item), $("#" + item + "Container"));

    }).click(function () {
        item = this.id;
        showImgBlock($("#" + item), $("#" + item + "Container"));
    });;
})();
```

What happens is now your check boxes have a class (`.imageBox`). When the document loads, each `.imageBox` is gone through to check the `id` of that specific check box where the name of the corresponding `div` container is pulled.

I think creating a function would be beneficial. This way you don't need to keep typing the same `if/else` block over and over. Remember, [duplicate code is bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code)

Also, I don't know if it's outside your project's scope or not, but in my Fiddle, I used `checkbox` rather than `radio` that way you can deselect them as well. Change it, keep it, up to you.

Comment: thanks guys, but the real problem here is having the show triggered on load instead of .click(function....

Comment: @User2194969 you want to show both images on load of the page?

Comment: so to explain the bigger picture here. I've got a form with a radio button to 'add an image'. stage 1 of the form is for the author. stage 2 of the form is for the content editor. so the form is completed and passed to the content editor. if the radio button is checked at stage 1 the div is shown. when this form is passed to stage 2 I need the div to still be shown. hope this explains my problem further

Comment: That's all well and good @user2194969. You should add that to your original question at the top.

Comment: are both stages on one page? Or is stage 2 on a completely new page? Update your question!

Comment: @Christopher I think this a winner! I've got to test in the system but it looks good! I'll let you know once I've tested it. Thanks man!

Comment: @user2194969, I simplified it further.